# Load text file contents into JavaScript in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, svg, text, sprockets

I have an SVG file that I want to dynamically load, inline, via JavaScript in my Rails application.  I need to load the SVG inline so that I can apply a CSS `fill` property to it.

I'd rather not load the SVG file via AJAX to avoid potential lag before the SVG is visible.

Ideally what I'd like to do is to tell Rails that, in my `app/assets/icons/` directory, I have icons `calendar.svg` and `phone.svg`, and that Rails (Sprockets?) should take the contents of those SVG files and set them as string values in a JavaScript object `SVG`, so that I may access them in my JavaScript code like this:

```
var view = {
  render: function () {
    this.element.innerHTML = SVG['app/assets/icons/calendar.svg'];
  }
};
```

Preferably, the solution is generalized to more than just SVGs, and I could potentially load any data in text format via JS, e.g. `TEXT['app/assets/icons/calendar.svg']` or even `TEXT['app/assets/etc/some-text-file.text']`.

Is there any way to do this in Rails?

Comment: What's stopping you from putting the contents of SVG within your view template (eg. ERB)?

Comment: I could, but that will not scale well, since if I have lots of SVGs in the HTML returned from my server, it will take longer for the browser to finish downloading the HTML and display the page; whereas if I load the SVGs in one network request (perhaps the JS request that I already have to make), then that loading can be deferred until after there is something on the page for the user to look at.

Comment: Another answer to that question is that the application is a SPA, and for lots of architectural reasons the view needs to be created with JS rather than an ERB template.

Comment: Now I am confused. You said "inline, via JavaScript in my Rails application." which means render the content of SVG file server side. But now you say "SPA" and the content should be created client side

Comment: My Rails application has a single, simple view.  An `application.js` file is generated via the asset pipeline.  This `application.js` makes the application a SPA, because it dynamically generates the HTML for the page.  When I say that I want to load the SVG "inline", I mean I want to do `htmlElement.innerHTML = '<svg><shape></shape></svg>'`, rather than load an external SVG like `<img src="shape.svg">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up writing a sprockets transformer for this: https://github.com/cloversites/js-text-rails

```
$ bundle install js-text-rails
```

require your files, e.g. in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js:`

```
//= require_tree ../images/icons
```

Where `app/assets/images/icons` contains the file `envelope.svg`.

Anywhere in your application's JavaScript code, access the text file contents via the global SVG variable:

```
var envelopeIcon = SVG['icons/envelope'];
// Do something with `envelopeIcon`...
```